# How to estimate cost of aws backup service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

I'm a noob in AWS, I'm trying to estimate my cost on aws service backup. I don't find the same cost when I'm using  aws calculator.

Hello all,
I hope somebody can help me. I'm trying to estimate my cost of AWS Backup service.
For example :
We have 10 GB data
We do weekly backup and have 28 days retention.
and the cost is 0.11$ GB / month.
So that means we save :
week 1 : 10GB we keep this backup 28 days in month
week 2 : 10GB we keep this backup 21 days in month then 7 days next month
week 3 : 10GB we keep this backup 14 days in month then 14 days next month
week 4 : 10GB we keep this backup 7 days in month then 21 days next month

The cost is 0.0036$ GB/day, so the cost is :
total = cost_week_1 + cost_week_2 + cost_week_3 + cost_week_4
total = (10 * 0.0036 * 28 ) + (10 * 0.0036 * 21 ) + (10 * 0.0036 * 14 ) + (10 * 0.0036 * 7 )
total = 1.02 + 0.756 + 0.504 + 0.252
total = 2.532$ to pay for the 1st month
but on aws calulator I got this :
Pricing calculations
Hourly Cold Retention (GB): 0
Daily Cold Retention (GB): 0
Weekly Cold Retention (GB): 0
Monthly Cold Retention (GB): 0
USD Average Monthly Cold: 0 USD
Hourly Retention (GB): 0
Daily Retention (GB): 0
28 days warm retention (weekly) / 30 days per month = 0.9333 Monthly retention (weekly)
0.9333 Monthly retention (weekly) x 10 Total storage = 9.333 Weekly Retention (GB)
Weekly Retention (GB): 9.333
Monthly Retention (GB): 0
10 Total storage + 9.333 weekly Retention = 19.33 Warm Capacity (GB)
19.33 warm capacity x 0.11 USD backup price = 2.1263 USD average monthly warm
USD Average Monthly Warm: 2.1263 USD
Total DynamoDB Backup Cost (monthly): 2.13 USD

Does anybody can help me ?

Thanks